# sizeof *this object

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <cstdio>

class myc {
    int dummy;
public:
    int si(){return sizeof(*this);}
};

class d_myc : public myc {
    int d_dummy;
};

int main() {
    myc a;
    d_myc b;
    printf("%d %d\n%d %d", a.si(), b.si(), sizeof(a), sizeof(b));
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
4 4
4 8
```

I expected :

```
4 8
4 8
```

Why were my expectations wrong?

Comment: I've removed the C tag, because this clearly isn't C.

Comment: `class`, etc. are C++ constructs; this code wouldn't compile in C, so this is a C++ question.  (And `cstdio` is C++, not C.)

Comment: I'm a little worried here about what you might be planning to do with the `sizeof` information...

Comment: I just wanted to check sizes of objects :D

Comment: The `sizeof` operator yields a `size_t` result, not an `int`.  The `%d` format requires an int argument.  For size_t, use `"%zu"` if your system supports it, or use `"%lu"` and cast to `unsigned long`.  (Yes, there are systems where it makes a difference.)

Comment: Im sure my program will give you same results on any (16/32/64 bit)system.

Comment: If there are virtual pointers and one more class hierarchy your expectations will go wrong again! :)

Comment: @Keith : Or, this being C++, just use `std::cout` and obviate the issue altogether... ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, of course, I was going to mention that.  No, really I was!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`sizeof` is resolved at compile-time, not run-time.  So `sizeof(*this)` is equivalent to `sizeof(myc)`.

Comment: And, importantly, acts on the static type of the expression its given, which in this case is `myc`.

Comment: So if you made si virtual, and copy/pasted it in each class, then it would work correctly?

Comment: @ildjarn: Even if it were virtual, it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Oli : Yeah, I edited that out seconds after I edited it in. :-P

Comment: @Oli: what? Sure it does make a difference if it's virtual, because then in `d_myc::si` the static type of `*this` is `d_myc`.

Comment: There are some cases of runtime sizeof, e.g. size of VLA. It make compiler writers a bit mor unhappy.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Sure, yes, if you make the function virtual and then override it.  @ildjarn's comment was originally implying that simply making `myc::si` virtual would make a difference.

Comment: @osgx: True.  (Although that's C99, not C++.)

Comment: runtime sizeof is GNU extension of C++. I think this is common extension.

Comment: @osgx: That's entirely possible!  But I never investigate such things, because they're non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved at compile time:

```
class myc {
    int dummy;
public:
    int si(){return sizeof(*this);}
};
```

i.e. `*this` is always myc and will never be `d_myc`.
To get what you want you will have to override the function in `d_myc` to do the same in the derived as the base.  This is because `sizeof(d_myc)` includes the base class too.